# Not able to access File Sharing and Printer in the same Network

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I  have group of 15 PC with Windows 7. All computers are connected through same network.
File and Printer Sharing Service is not Working.
Trouble Shooting steps taken by me as below:

1. A PC can access own shared folder through hostname but not through IP address.
2. Remote can not access shared folder either by host name or IP address
3. Ping Response is Proper
4. TCP NetBIOS Service is Running properly
5. Firewall is Off
6. Remote PC  is accessible through remote desktop Connection.

Please help me out to access shared folder.

Comment: Does your network have a DNS server and do the clients register with it? when you ping another device can you ping it by name AND by IP Address? have you edited the hosts file?

Comment: Thank You Sir For your kind response. We do not have DNS Server. Yes it is ping through IP Address and Name. No i have not edited through host file.

Comment: do all machines have a static ip address or are they assigned automatically(DHCP)?  Two things you need to look into, 1) permissions. You assign permissions when you create the share. Make sure the machines and users have permission to access the share. 2)Hostname lookups(DNS) When you give the machine a name it needs to look up that name and find the ipaddress associated with that name. A DNS server does this for you. With no DNS server, a good substitute is to edit the hosts file on each machine. So check permissions and provide a way to lookup names.

Comment: Every thing was working fine before forcefully auto update of OS from Microsoft. Update was not successfully completed. Due to this file and printer share stopped. Please let me know how to recover it.